# Is it possible to join two tables if table1.column value is in table2.column value

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two tables i.e. *`users`* and *`actions_performed`*

`users` :  *id, name, etc*

`actions_performed` : *performed_by, action_id*

Now the values in *actions_performed* can be as `[ 'user:15', 'department:3', 'team:7' ]` etc

Now i want to fetch the action performed by a specific user `say id 1`

i am implementing the same in **Laravel 9**,

can someone please help me either with the `ORM relations` or even simple `SQL Queries`

```
Users::where( function($q) use($searchString){
        $q->crossJoin('actions_performed', function($q) use($searchString){
            $q->where('performed_by','LIKE','%user%')
                ->where('value','LIKE',"%$searchString%");
        });
    })
```

Comment: use `relational query` and `relational database` instead of string data of id

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @all

I achieved the same by below

```
$query->when(!empty($searchString), function($q1) use($searchString){
          $q1->join('actions_performed', \DB::raw("CONCAT('user:' , `users`. `id`)"), '=', 'actions.performed_by')
              ->where(function ($q2) use($searchString){
                  $q2->where('actions.performed_by', 'LIKE', "%$searchString%");
              });
      });
```